# Changing elements of a list affects/does not affect a derived list

Tags: python, list, element, immutability, mutability

I do not understand the following anomalous behavior with lists in Python, and would appreciate it if someone could throw some light:

Snippet 1:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
A = [myList]*3
print(A)
myList[2]=45
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 45, 4], [1, 2, 45, 4], [1, 2, 45, 4]]
```

This makes sense to me, since we did not perform an additional copy function to 'shield' A from element operations on myList.

Snippet 2:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
A = myList*3
print(A)
myList[2]=45
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why is a change to myList not reflected in A?

Comment: Because you're assigning a value for mylist[2] only after the assignment of `A` occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, you're duplicating 3 references to `myList` directly. In the second case, you're duplicating 3 references to the *contents* of `myList`, which leaves you with no connection to the original `myList`.